# Determine amount of memory cached by user in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, caching, sql-server-2014

I have a database with multiple users. There is a problem with cache that I need to take care of.

Is it possible to check what user cached the most data?

I know it won't resolve my problem but this is the information I needed.

I know it is possible to check which object uses how much memory cache. But I want to get information about users.

Answer (score 0):

You can get information about amount of memory, used by the queries of a user in point of time, from DMV [sys.dm_exec_sessions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx) from column `memory_usage`

> memory_usage / int /  Number of 8-KB pages of memory used by this
>   session. Is not nullable.

```
SELECT des.login_name
    ,SUM(memory_usage)*8 memory_usage_KB
FROM  sys.dm_exec_sessions des
WHERE des.is_user_process = 1
GROUP BY des.login_name
```

**EDITED**

Cached pages in buffer pool (and also execution plans in procedure cache) don't belong to any user, because they stay in there after completion of the query, that read this pages from disk into RAM, and they reused by other queries, which can belong to other sessions of many users.

Comment: it's for sure not the amount of cached data into database by that user.

Answer (score 0):

No, is not possible, because there is no correlation between buffer pool (cached data), procedure cache (execution plans), memory allocation and users (sessions).

If you have a performance problems I suggest you approach it as such and do proper investigation.  [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/) is a good start. Specifically for memory issues you can read [Monitor Memory Usage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176018.aspx), but you should first *prove* that memory usage is an issue.

As general advice do not approach experts by describing the issue as "there is a problem". Describe exactly the problem, the symptoms, any error message you experience, what exact investigation you did, how and what did you measure and what are the observed values.